# Why didn't the Septuagint translate 'ahabah to eros?

Tags: hebrew, greek, translation-philosophy, septuagint, song-of-songs

Song of Songs 2:7 in English ([NPJS](http://www.taggedtanakh.org/Chapter/Index/english-Songs-2)) reads:

> I adjure you, O maidens of Jerusalem,
>   By gazelles or by hinds of the field:
>   Do not wake or rouse
>   Love until it please!

As the [NET Bible](http://classic.net.bible.org/verse.php?book=Sos&chapter=2&verse=7) points out, "Love" in this passage almost certainly was meant as a personification of the abstract concept of romantic or (more to the point) sexual desire.  Like Hebrew, we only have one term that would work here: "Love".

The Septuagint [frequently](http://www.lrz.de/~hr/bible/loves.html) translates *'ahabah* <[0160](http://classic.net.bible.org/strong.php?id=0160)> to *agape* <[26](http://classic.net.bible.org/strong.php?id=26)>, as in this case.  But wouldn't a better word in Greek be [*eros*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eros_%28concept%29) for this particular verse?  Sure, in other passages where sex isn't meant (or strongly implied) it would make sense to avoid introducing an "erotic" connotation, but here [Love](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eros_%28god%29) is practically a character in the poem.  Why not use a Greek word that means the sort of sexual love that is clearly present in the original Hebrew?

Comment: This might not be answerable, since we can't really know the mind of ["the seventy"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septuagint#Naming_and_designation).  My question is closely related to [Has the meaning of "Love" changed enough to warrant substitutions in Bible translations?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/950)

Comment: There are actually multiple words for "love" in Hebrew: http://www.christinyou.net/Outlines/love.pdf. But I cannot answer this question beyond speculation (but I will speculate if that is acceptable).

Comment: See also http://www.theologyweb.com/campus/showthread.php?108306-Hebrew-words-for-love&s=8dee5bc1ebdd60ec47f6673c1b0ae187&p=2231287#post2231287

Comment: @Dan: I think _informed_ speculation is allowed.  I've [been known](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/251/68) to do it!

Comment: The Vulgate has: "I adjure you, O ye daughters of Jerusalem, by the roes, and the harts of the fields, that you stir not up, nor make the beloved [diléctam] to awake, till she please." That is, it doesn't take this  to be sexual love, but as referring to the spouse 'beloved.' 'Agape' love neither rules out nor explicitly entails sexual desire. I'm no expert on Hebrew, however.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Different ancient translators had different translation philosophies.  Some were very rigid and always used Greek word X for Hebrew word Y.  Others were more dynamic.  We can actually use these philosophies to determine when different translators are responsible for different books.  For example, the Greek of Numbers is **very** literal (except the name of the book.  The Hebrew is *Bmidbar* -*In the Wilderness* -, but the Greek is *Arithmoi*, which is where we get the name Numbers).  The LXX of Numbers is Greek vocabulary with Hebrew syntax.  This also works very nicely for text criticism.  When that pattern holds, we can be more certain that the Hebrew source was the same as in the BHS today.  When the pattern breaks, either there was a different Hebrew vorlage or the LXX Numbers was miscopied at some point.

IIRC, Exodus is not that way.  Exodus has less one-to-one and more what-word-best-translates-this-Hebrew-word-in-this-context attitude.  Genesis in the LXX shows both attitudes.  Gen 1-11 are very much in the word-for-word attitude, even so far as the *waw* conjunction **always** being translated with *kai*.  Gen 12-50, however, uses both *de* and *kai* for the *waw* conjunction.  Some books even achieve paraphrase status.

The question comes down to what is the translation philosophy of the Greek translators of Song of Songs?  Was the translator one of those who always uses the same Greek word for this Hebrew word?  Or was he more contextual?  Or even was he reading it allegorically?

As I do a word search on *'ahab* I see it is used 11 times in *Song of Songs.*  In the Septuagint of *Songs*, *'agape* also appears 11 times.  There is a one-to-one correspondence.  *agape* is the only word used in Song of Songs to translate *'ahab*.

Though I can't be sure of the whole philosophy without a more extensive analysis of the LXX of Songs, it appears that with *'ahab* at least, the translator had a one-to-one correspondence in mind.

Comment: This is very useful information.  Once a translator had decided that _agape_ was the correct translation of _'ahab_, it makes some sense that they stuck to it.  I suppose if a translator had started with a different text, _eros_ would have been a poor choice because of sexual connotations and when they got to the _Song of Songs_ they decided to be consistent.  Does that seems plausible?

Comment: That does seem plausible.

Comment: On the side point about the name of the book, the Greek Arithmoi is actually a translation of ספר הפקודים (book of counting); the Hebrew name "In the desert" comes from far into the Middle Ages

Answer (score 6):

I appreciate the question. I think it stems from some wrong presuppositions, though - namely, that sexual "love" is strictly within the domain of *eros* rather than *agape*. I agree that sexual love can be *eros*, but it is not the exclusive owner of it. In fact, all pure, other-centered love is *agape.* This applies just as much to the sexual arena as anything else.

*Eros,* on the other hand, is the enemy of *agape* and, in fact, has no hint of other-centeredness. This is why the LXX translates *ahab* as *agape,* I do believe, because they understood that the Song of Solomon describes an other-centered love - even within the context of sex - which *eros* has nothing to do with.

I would highly recommend reading the book [*Agape and Eros*](http://www.carstenjohnsen.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/CJAgape.pdf) by Carsten Johnsen, for a very good  treatment of this important topic. Among other things he writes: "I am not saying one single disparaging word about the natural beauty in a woman’s body. It certainly is not Eros who has had anything to do with creating that. The Creator’s name is Jesus Christ, and He is Agape. It is not Eros who has made sex a pleasant experience, any more than he has made strawberries taste delicious. It is God, and God only, who has prepared all things that are good – really good. It is He who has invented feminine beauty ([*Agape and Eros,*](http://www.carstenjohnsen.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/CJAgape.pdf) p. 40).

Comment: Welcome to our _Biblical Hermeneutics_ Q&A site!  Thank you for challenging the question.  Thinking about it, I can see that the Greek concepts don't really map perfectly to the Hebrew ones.  Depending on how you understand _eros_, there's every reason to avoid that word and it's connotations.  Also, I really appreciate the book recommendation, though it may be a while before I get to it.  Does Johnsen deal with Lewis' _The Four Loves_, by the way?  That's the primary reason I know enough of the Greek to even _have_ a question. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Look, according to **Matthew 22:36-40**, probably, there are three types of love (and many people forget or even don't know):

> Master, which is the great commandment in the law? Jesus said unto
> him, Thou shalt love the Lord thy God with all thy **heart**, and with all
> thy **soul**, and with all thy **mind**. This is the first and great
> commandment. And the second is like unto it, Thou shalt love thy
> neighbor as thyself. On these two commandments hang all the law and
> the prophets. (KJV)

This passage describes, Christ (who was jewish) saying about the biggest prayer jewish people have, the *Shemah*. The word heart seems to be associated with the idea of love, since לֶאֱהֹב is "to love" and "heart" is לֵב, so they are very similar.

So, as in jewish thinking, as said by Rabbi Jack Abramowitz, there are the following types of love for G'd:

- A servant might love his master because the master treats him **kindly**;
- A servant might love his master because the master overlooks his misdeeds and grants him **forgiveness**;
- A servant might love his master simply because of the master's own **inherent** **greatness** and not because of any favor that the servant expects to receive.

Observe the **Deuteronmy 6:5**:

> וְאָ֣הַבְתָּ֔ אֵ֖ת יְהֹוָ֣ה אֱלֹהֶ֑יךָ בְּכׇל־**לְבָבְךָ֥**
> וּבְכׇל־**נַפְשְׁךָ֖** וּבְכׇל־**מְאֹדֶֽךָ**׃

But I will focus on the **third** type above that contains the three forms of love, this is: love with heart, with soul and with mind (actually it's might **מְאֹדֶךָ**). Indeed, לִנְפֹּשׁ means "to relax", it's type of love that you fulfill by having "peace in the soul",it's similar to the word **נַפְשְׁךָ֖**.

Now, observe that **ahavah** (אהבה which comes from לֶאֱהֹב) is the word for "love", and is the form of **love** that's associated with the **choice**, so it's not properly associated with anything else, it's as if the **heart is the mind**, that's why we don't translate the last type of love as "love with all your mind" because it would be counted twice, we translate it as "might", for this is the process of "doing". The best word that fits instead of love in the above passage is **אַוֶּ֖ה** (Proverbs 21:10, Deuteronomy 12:20, Proverbs 23:6).