# How should Psalm 22:16 read?

Tags: hebrew, psalms, textual-criticism, niv, new-english-translation

Psalm 22:16 seems textually quite difficult. The [NET](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Psalms+22:16) for example reads:

> Yes, wild dogs surround me –
> a gang of evil men crowd around me;
> like a lion they pin my hands and feet.

Yet, they note that the Hebrew literally translates: "like a lion, my hands and my feet." and that "This reading is often emended because it is grammatically awkward," while suggesting that "perhaps its awkwardness is by rhetorical design."

The [NIV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=psalm+22:16&version=NIV), however, reads:

> Dogs surround me,
> a pack of villains encircles me;
> they pierce[a] my hands and my feet.

The footnote says: "Dead Sea Scrolls and some manuscripts of the Masoretic Text, Septuagint and Syriac; most manuscripts of the Masoretic Text me, / like a lion."

Even from a couple footnotes there is a lot going on here. Which rendering should be considered the older/original text?

Comment: a detailed evidence here. The text is found in DSS Nahal Hever (5/6HevPs) and LXX. https://ladderofjacob.com/2020/08/06/psalm22/

Comment: One For Israel (I'm not affiliated) has great resources on this which show that the Dead Sea Scrolls (older) state "pierced" but the MT (newer) states "lion" - it may have been intentionally changed "for the greater good" (AKA evil) in the MT because it sounds too much like Jesus and Jesus was / is far from popular (even hated) in Rabbinic Judaism

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A good case can be made for the reading as a verb instead of a noun with a preposition prefixed.

Regarding verse 16, Walter Kaiser (*[The Messiah in the Old Testament](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/031020030X)*, footnote 10 pg. 115 and 116) lays out his argument for the verb by referencing the Vulgate, the Syriac, and the Septuagint, all of which have verbs. He takes the form *ka'ari* as the irregular plural for *ka'arim*. This form is a plural participle of *kur*. While the proper form would be *kar*, the vowel points are not without precedent: Hosea 10:14 (*qa'm*); Ezekiel 28:24, 26 (*sa'tim*). He then defends the interpretation:

1. The Hebrew Usage. *kur* is then synonomous with the verb *karah* - "to bore through," which often occurs. Such a permutation of the verbs *ayin''waw* and *lamad''hah* is common.
2. The testimony of the LXX uses *oruxzan cheiras mou kai podas mou* ("they have dug/pierced my hands and feet") as well as the Syriac *perforarunt* and the Vulgate *foderunt*. (Jerome outside the Vulgate, translates the Hebrew into *fixerant*.)
3. In Arabic, the agreement of *kur* with *karah* exists. Though this is not an argument ender, the appearance in a cognate language does lend support.

Regarding the Septuagint rendering the Hebrew as a verb, the rest of the psalm needs to be compared. If the Greek and Hebrew agree closely throughout the rest of the psalm, then we can be more sure that the Hebrew text was a verb. If other parts of this psalm are translated more loosely, then the testimony of the Septuagint here is lessened. Kaiser refers to the LXX as a direct translation. In places, it certainly is (Numbers has even been called "Greek vocabulary on top of Hebrew syntax"). However, in other sections of the Tanakh, the translation is rather freeform.

[Aquila](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquila_of_Sinope), in his Greek translation of the Tanakh first rendered the word in question with the verb *eschuan*, reading the Hebrew as a later Hebrew word meaning "make dirty." However, as he could not support this related to the rest of the psalm, his second edition agrees with that of [Symachius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmachus_the_Ebionite) and uses "they have bound." Both Aquila and Symachius are Jewish (converts to Judaism, it appears), though after the time of Jesus.

A discovery of a Hebrew scroll at [Nahal Hever](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discoveries_in_the_Judean_Desert) renders the word as כר[ו ]ידי. Very detailed grammatical information may be found [here](http://lists.ibiblio.org/pipermail/b-hebrew/2009-December/040121.html). Some scholars debate if the Septuagint translators had a text reading כארו instead of כארי. That is, the final letter is a longer *waw* instead of the short *yod*. Such a mistake between the *yod* and *waw* has been noted before<sup>1</sup> and the misreading is easy to make. Others note that the Hebrew word for "lion" appears in the psalm both before (13/14) and after (21/22), but the spelling is different from verse 16/17. Before and after both use אריה.

---

1. One of my seminary professors graduated from Hebrew Union. His best friend there did his doctoral dissertation on determining *yod* and *waw* in parts of the Dead Sea Scrolls where it could not be determined by sight if the letter was one of the above and Hebrew words could be formed by more than one option. His research involved calipers and magnifying glasses.

Comment: While it is possible for sloppy handwriting to create ambiguity between כארי and כארו, the latter doesn't mean “pierce”.  The scribe would have to also delete the alef, making כרו, which means “to dig”.

Comment: The vav vs. Yod is not a mistake, it is typical scribal practice of the day. https://youtu.be/MImJI68_-Po

Comment: Wasn't *aleph* sometimes used as a vowel indicator in the very ancient texts?

Comment: @SolaGratia, before the nikkud, yes, it was sometimes used for long, a-class  vowels.

Comment: @DanielbenNoach The aleph could be a spelling variation, and/or  a vowel indicator.   So   כארו  could mean the same as  כרו  without the need to delete the aleph.

Answer (score 1):

There is always going to be the argument that the Septuagint is older than the Masoretic text and therefore takes precedence.

Translation from Hebrew to Greek or any other language has difficulties.  The Dead Sea Scrolls in general provides strong support of the ‘MT’ translation.

***Supporting evidence***

Psalms 22:16 (17 in the Jewish Tanakh)

The translation given is:  "Dogs surround me, a pack of villains encircles me; they ***pierce*** my hands and my feet." (NIV)

Pierce has been translated from the Hebrew word *** Ka-a-ri***

Jewish scriptures
This reading is based upon the Masoretic Hebrew Texts that reads as follows
Psalm 22:17 (Hebrew text) כִּ֥י סְבָב֗וּנִי כְּלָ֫בִ֥ים עֲדַ֣ת מְ֭רֵעִים הִקִּיפ֑וּנִי כָּ֝אֲרִ֗י יָדַ֥י וְרַגְלָֽי׃
Here we can see Masoretic Text clearly has כָּ֝אֲרִ֗י kā-’ă-rî,

So should read - P22:17 17 For dogs have encompassed me; a company of evil-doers have inclosed me; ***like a lion,*** they are at my hands and my feet.

***Kā-’ă-rî,*** means like a lion, there is no argument against this. Ari ă-rî, means ‘lion’ and the prefix kā Ka means ‘like’. The literal translation is ***‘like a lion’.***
Hebrew, the phrase “they have pierced” is possibly ***kaaru*** [having said that ***there is no verb in the Hebrew Language כָּֽאֲרִ֔וּ (ka’aru).***   At best it can be understood as ‘dug’ or ‘dig’ as in a hole for a well for example.

Isaiah kaari is translated ***as a lion***

***Isaiah 38: 13*** I reckoned till morning, that, ***as a lion,*** so will he break all my bones: from day even to night wilt thou make an end of me.

***Psalms 22:21 reads***
Save me from the mouth of the ***lion!*** You have rescued me from the horns of the wild oxen!

***Greek Septuagint has the word ὢρυξαν, ōruxsan, which actually means “they dug”***

***common animal motif***

Passages before & after Psalm 22:17. Psalm 17:11-12 and 35:17 are sister passages to 22:17

“Many bulls surround me; ***strong bulls*** of Bashan encircle me.” (Psalm 22:12)

***“Roaring lions*** that tear their prey open their mouths wide against me.” (Psalm 22:13)

***“Dogs surround me,*** a pack of villains encircles me“ (Psalm 22:16a)

They are ***like a lion*** hungry for prey, like a fierce ***lion*** crouching in cover. (Psalm 17:12)

How long, Lord, will you look on? Rescue me from their ravages, my precious life from these ***lions.*** (Psalm 35:17)

Numbers 23:24 (veka'ari), and I as a young lion

Numbers 24:9 (ka'ari), like a lion

Ezekiel 22:25 (ka'ari), like a lion

PSALM 91:10-16 ***no harm will overtake you,*** no disaster will come near your tent.11 For he will command his angels concerning you to guard you in all your ways; 12 they will lift you up in their hands, so that you ***will not strike your foot against a stone.*** 13 You will tread on the ***lion*** and the cobra; you will trample the ***great lion*** and the serpent. 14 “Because he loves me,” says the LORD, ***“I will rescue him;*** I will protect him, for he acknowledges my name. 15 ***He will call on me, and I will answer him;*** I will be with him in trouble, I will deliver him and honor him. 16 ***With long life I will satisfy him and show him My salvation.”***

[again we have lion & will not strike his foot let alone have holes]

*** Nahal Hever Cave***

The Nahal Hever Cave - second century manuscript which some say supports the reading of “pierced” in Psalm 22 - כָּֽאֲרִ֔וּ (ka’aru)

The writing on this script is not sharp or uniform. Some argue that the anomaly is due to scribe’s poor handwriting / spelling. Others say the ink is to faded to be sure.

The very next word ***“my hands.”*** The Hebrew word in Psalm 22:17 is יָדַ֥י (yadai). The Nahal Hever scribe, however, misspelled this word by placing an extra letter ה (hey) at the end of the word. Thus, the Nahal Hever 5/6HevPs reads יָ֭דֶיהָ instead of the correct יָדַ֥י (yadai). The Hebrew word יָ֭דֶיהָ (yadehah) means ***“her hands,”*** not “my hands.”

So, its arguably how reliable these documents are and ***do not pre-date other documents.***

***General points***

Dead Sea Scrolls at Qumran. Other segments of Psalm 22 were discovered, but not this section.

***Matthew*** was clearly familiar with Psalms as he quotes Psalms 22:1 in Matt 27:46 and many other quotes from Psalms and OT books – yet he does not mention such an important point that will directly correlate with the crucifixion.

Paul who quotes OT numerous times and the gospel writers familiar with the OT don’t mention this.

***Other supporting evidence***

If Jesus hands and feet were pierced & there were holes as implied such as the Thomas story in John, this would cause a conflict with other passages.

Psalms 34:20 & 22 - 20He ***protects all his bones; not one of them will be broken***

[There not going to be little nails and no matter how experienced they are in the crucifixion; they are not going ***care*** about putting nails in such a precise  manner to ensure no bones are broken – just unrealistic]

Astonishingly - No mention of any pierce / holes / wounds etc… [unlike Thomas – see https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/77233/33268 ]

Luke 24:39 - "Behold my hands and my feet, that it is I myself: handle me, and see; for a spirit hath not flesh and bones, as ye see me have".

22 - The LORD ***will rescue his servants;*** no one who takes refuge in him will be condemned.

Based on the above the strongest argument would be that it is ‘lion’ & not ‘pierced’

Comment: Man, I am backing you up +1. Have you read my answer for https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/78683/should-cainan-be-included-or-excluded-from-the-geneology-of-jesus  I give more detail on the Septuagint.

Comment: @Kapandaria many thanks for your +1's - Your link above - yes very interesting/helpful information, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Overview**

> Dogs surround me; a pack of evil ones close in on me; <sup>d</sup>like lions [they maul] my hands and feet.<sup>d</sup> (Psalm 22:17 NJPS)
> <sub>d-d *With Rashi; cf. Isaiah 38.13*</sub>
> כי סבבוני כלבים עדת מרעים הקיפוני כארי ידי ורגלי

Commenting on this portion of the Psalm, Adele Berlin and Marc Zvi Brettler say:

> A graphic description of mortal illness. The psalmist feels his body stop working and disintegrate. He sees himself die , his body so dried up that it turns to dust. The scorners are like dogs (and lions, according to the NJPS) hunting prey (cf. v. 14). They gloat at his death and are eager to take his possessions.<sup>`1`</sup>

The difficulty with the verse stems from the word, כארי which appears to come from כָּרָה meaning [to dig or to excavate](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H3738&t=KJV). Ellicott's Commentary details the issue:

> They pierced.—The word thus rendered has formed a battle-ground for controversy. As the Hebrew text at present stands the word reads kāarî (like a lion). (Comp. [Isaiah 38:13](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%2038%3A13&version=ESV;WLC).) But no intelligible meaning can be got out of “like a lion my hands and my feet.” Nor does the plan commend itself of dividing the verses differently, and reading, “The congregation of wicked men have gathered round me like a lion. On my hands and my feet I can tell all my bones.” The punctuation of the text must therefore be given up, and a meaning sought by changing the reading.<sup>`2`</sup>

As Ellicott notes, treating the word as "lions" creates problems, as the NJPS translation reflects. So "they maul" must be added to make sense of the passage and so "lions" is hardly an improvement. On the other hand, "they pierced" as in [many Christian translations](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Psalm%2022:16) or "they pinned" as the NET, arguably are better than "lions;" yet they too fail to convey the proper sense of the Hebrew.

**Exegesis**
"Pierced" or "pinned" is seeing the passage through the lens of the Crucifixion. This may be criticized from the literal text, but it is Jesus' words from the cross which invite this perspective:

> And about the ninth hour Jesus cried out with a loud voice, saying, “Eli, Eli, lema sabachthani?” that is, “My God, my God, why have you forsaken me?” (Matthew 27:46  [Mark 15:34](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%2015%3A34&version=ESV)) [ESV]

> My God, my God, why have you abandoned me...(Psalm 22:2 NJPS)

As Jewish commentators note, [Isaiah 38:13](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/isaiah/38-13.htm) uses the same word, which is rendered as lions there. However, Isaiah also gives this message about the prophetic word:

> <sup>8</sup> For my thoughts are not your thoughts, neither are your ways my ways, declares the LORD. <sup>9</sup> For as the heavens are higher than the earth, so are my ways higher than your ways and my thoughts than your thoughts. <sup>10</sup> “For as the rain and the snow come down from heaven and do not return there but water the earth, making it bring forth and sprout, giving seed to the sower and bread to the eater, <sup>11</sup> so shall my word be that goes out from my mouth; it shall not return to me empty, but it shall accomplish that which I purpose, and shall succeed in the thing for which I sent it. (Isaiah 55)

The example from the natural world is the word of God works *like rain and snow that come down from heaven and do not return there but water the earth...* Rain waters the earth when it falls, but snow waters later only after it melts. Thus, an  initial and later meaning are possible in a passage which is prophetic. In Psalm 22, the "snow" is reading the passage in the light of the Crucifixion.

In that case, the question is how does "digging" my hands and feet apply? "Pierced" or "pinned" misstate the action by describing the **result** after they the hands and feet were "digged." The meaning of כָּרָה as it applies to the crucifixion is in the process of **finding** the correct spot in which to drive the nails. The Roman soldier would have to "dig around" Jesus' body to make certain of the placement of a nail before he could drive them through a hand or foot and into the cross.

**Conclusion**
Any passage which speaks prophetically is fully understood after the "rain and snow." In the case of Psalm 22, the later meaning is seen in the Crucifixion. While "pierced" or "pinned" is not inaccurate because they describe what happened because of the "digging;" it would be better if the correct meaning was given:

> Dogs surround me; a pack of evil ones close in on me; **they dig** my hands and feet.

The question then becomes how does "digging" my hands and feet make sense? The answer is, the nails must be correctly placed in order to support the body and so the Roman soldier would not simply nail a victim to the cross. They would carefully "dig" into the part of the body before driving the nail and in so doing avoid rupturing an artery of placing the nail in away which would not support the body.

---

<sub>1. Adele Berlin and Marc Zvi Brettler, *The Jewish Study Bible*, Edited by Adele Berlin and Marc Zvi Brettler, Oxford University Press, 2004, p.1306 (note the NJPS numbering is 22:17)</sub>
<sub>2. [Ellicott](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/psalms/22-16.htm)</sub>